# how to use slf4j with multiple class in java spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

I want to write log for my process from multi file java in 1 file log in java spring.
This is my logback.xml file:

```
<configuration>
<property name="HOME_LOG" value="logs"/>
<appender name="001" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${HOME_LOG}/001/application.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${HOME_LOG}/001.%d{yyyy-MM-dd ss}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- each archived file, size max 10MB -->
        <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 20GB, it will delete old archived file -->
        <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>
        <!-- 60 days to keep -->
        <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<logger name="001" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="001"/>
</logger>
```

Now I want to write log from 2 file java is : demo1.java and demo2.java. This is code java :

```
file demo1.java
private final static Logger log001 = LoggerFactory.getLogger("001");
log001.info("I am java 1");

file demo2.java
private final static Logger log001 = LoggerFactory.getLogger("001");
log001.info("I am java 2");
```

I want to my log file can show 2 text : 'I am java 1' and 'I am java 2'. Now it is writing override.

Comment: Don't fully understand your question. Could you post the current log info that is printed and what you'd like to see.

Comment: Also looks like logger "002" is undefined. LoggerFactory.getLogger("002");

Comment: I edited it, Can you help me? @maitreyak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your log file is overwritten on each run, is due to the way you configured the `fileNamePattern` in the `rollingPolicy`, i.e your application.log is created anew on each run since the file pattern granularity is in the seconds `{yyyy-MM-dd ss}`

**Quick fix: change**

`<fileNamePattern>${HOME_LOG}/001.%d{yyyy-MM-dd ss}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>`

to

`<fileNamePattern>${HOME_LOG}/001.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>`

Comment: I don't understand, in this code, I can not create file .gz after 1s?